# Do I need Transit visa or visitor visa for my travel through Germany (2 lay overs in Germany while returning from India to US)

Tags: transit, schengen-visas

I need some help in order to understand the type of visa required to travel through Germany airports. My itinerary to india is Boston-Munich-Mumbai and my return flight is Mumbai-Munich-Frankfurt-Boston. I hold indian passport and have US visa in the form of approved I797 but passport is not stamped while going from US to India. The plan is to get passport stamped and take the return flight as mentioned above. While going from US to India, I just have one layover in Munich but while coming back I have two lay overs- one in Munich and other in Frankfurt (both in the same country).
Do I need a German visa for my returning flight to US? I am really confused- Do I need a airport transit visa? or Do I need a visitor visa? Basically what type of visa I need to get for my round trip- US to india, and India to US.

The more I read, the more I get confused. I tried calling German embassy in boston and also Lufthansa airline but I don't have any response yet. The whole terminology is confusing to me- Schengen vs transit or if they are same?

Can anyone please provide me the response based on my case and if someone in the same situation or have traveled in the past.

Comment: As a rule transport between two airports is landside, that means that you need a visa. As there are no 'double airport transport visa' you will have to apply for a normal Schengen visa, and those are the same for whether you want to come into the area for a few hours or for a few months.

Comment: Airport transit visas apply only if you remain in the airport without passing through immigration control.  To fly between Munich and Frankfurt you need to pass through immigration control.  Therefore you need a normal Schengen short-stay visa.  (That visa will also fulfill the airport transit visa requirement that you would otherwise need to meet for your outbound journey, so be sure to report your entire itinerary in your application.)